# Im 14 and I can feel a lump in my left breast. Is this normal?

Tags: breast, nipples, large-size

Yesterday my left breast was kind of sore so I took of my bra and started feeling around it. I could feel a hard lump under where my nipple is which is quite big. Today it s only sore when I start to prod it but otherwise I can t feel it, but now my skin is red around my nipple where i was prodding last night. I have never had this before and it s only in 1 boob, I m really worried and I don t know what it is.

Comment: I think you should have a Dr check it out.

Comment: It's most likely perfectly normal development of your breasts occurring but you should never ignore any new lump or abnormality. You need to see a doctor and have it looked at. We can't offer personal medical advice here. Nobody on the internet can tell you what that is no matter what they claim.